# HTML email images breaking on mobile despite inline styling

Tags: mobile, html-email

I need to send an html email but the images show gaps on mobile. I have used Campaign Monitor's inliner but still the images show gaps on mobile. It is absolutely fine on my laptop.

I'm using Gmail client to check the email on both laptop and mobile.

Can someone please help?

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<title>DR. EARTH &ndash; Results on Wheat</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="Dr. Earth results on wheat, plant growth promoter, extracted from sapropel, it really works, better root growth, increase in yield by 7.5 quintals per acre, arrest of 'kamal bant' disease, increases crop yield by 30%, improves quality of produce, improves resistance to diseases, VRS Agritech, Designed by BK Suru">
<meta name="author" content="Bhavesh Kumar Suru - www.BKsuru.com">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 2010 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, height=device-height"/>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
<style type="text/css">
html,body{min-height:100%}
body {
    background-color: #999999 !important;
}
img.map, map area{
    outline: none;
}
img {
display: block !important;
}
.border {
    border:solid #999 thin;
}
.shadow {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 2px #777;
       -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 2px #777;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 2px #777;
}
.rounded {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px !important;
}
.rounded-top {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px !important;
}
.rounded-bottom {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px !important;
}
p {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:0.025em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:12px !important;
    color:#222; 
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    line-height:18px !important;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="min-height:100%;background-color:#999999 !important;" >

<p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;letter-spacing:0.025em;text-align:center;font-size:12px !important;color:#222;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px;line-height:18px !important;" ><a href="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat" target="_new" style="text-decoration:none;color:#000;" >Open this email in browser</a></p>

<table width="800" height="1713" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Table_01" border="0" class="border shadow rounded" style="border-width:thin;border-style:solid;border-color:#999;-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 10px 2px #777;-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 10px 2px #777;box-shadow:0px 2px 5px 2px #777;-moz-border-radius-topleft:15px;-moz-border-radius-topright:15px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright:15px;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:15px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius:15px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:15px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:15px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:15px;border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px !important;" >
<tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_01.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="57" border="0" usemap="#Map5" class="rounded-top" style="display:block !important;-moz-border-radius-topleft:15px;-moz-border-radius-topright:15px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius:15px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:15px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_02.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="57" border="0" usemap="#Map4" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_03.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_04.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_05.jpg" width="800" height="58" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_06.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_07.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_08.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_09.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_10.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_11.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_12.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_13.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_14.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_15.jpg" width="800" height="58" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_16.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_17.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_18.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_19.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_20.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_21.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_22.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_23.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_24.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_25.jpg" width="800" height="58" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_26.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_27.jpg" width="800" height="57" alt="" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_28.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="57" border="0" usemap="#Map3" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_29.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="57" border="0" usemap="#Map" style="display:block !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.drearth.in/campaigns/results-on-wheat/images/index_30.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="57" border="0" usemap="#Map2" class="rounded-bottom" style="display:block !important;-moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;-moz-border-radius-topright:0px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright:15px;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:15px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:15px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:15px;border-radius:0px 0px 15px 15px !important;" ></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;letter-spacing:0.025em;text-align:center;font-size:12px !important;color:#222;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px;line-height:18px !important;" >If you do NOT wish to receive any future communication from <b>Dr. Earth</b> <br>then you can unsubscribe by email to <a href="mailto:unsubscribe@drearth.in?subject=Please unsubscribe me from your mailing list" style="text-decoration:none;color:#000;" >unsubscribe@drearth.in</a></p>

<p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;letter-spacing:0.025em;text-align:center;font-size:12px !important;color:#222;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px;line-height:18px !important;" >© 2015 <b>VRS Agritech Pvt. Ltd.</b> All Rights Reserved</p>

<map name="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="135,39,319,60" href="http://www.vrsagritech.com" target="_tab" style="outline-style:none;" >
  <area shape="rect" coords="565,14,769,33" href="http://www.drearth.in" target="_tab" style="outline-style:none;" >
  <area shape="rect" coords="502,40,767,62" href="mailto:customercare@drearth.in" target="_new" style="outline-style:none;" >
  <area shape="rect" coords="30,0,127,48" href="http://www.vrsagritech.com" target="_tab" style="outline-style:none;" >
</map>

<map name="Map2">
  <area shape="rect" coords="3,21,301,53" href="http://www.vrsagritech.com" target="_tab" style="outline-style:none;" >
  <area shape="rect" coords="663,21,795,53" href="http://www.bksuru.com" target="_tab" style="outline-style:none;" >
</map>

<map name="Map3">
  <area shape="rect" coords="30,51,125,67" href="http://www.vrsagritech.com" target="_tab" style="outline-style:none;" >
</map>

<map name="Map4">
  <area shape="rect" coords="209,-1,594,44" href="http://www.drearth.in" target="_tab" style="outline-style:none;" >
</map>

<map name="Map5">
  <area shape="rect" coords="209,30,594,66" href="http://www.drearth.in" target="_tab" style="outline-style:none;" >
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

**Mobile screenshot:**

[image]

**Laptop screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Used DIVs instead and style="display:block;" for each image, and it worked like a charm.